# Javascript (jQuery) introspection

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, introspection

I am hoping to write some kind of doc generator for my jQuery plugins. All my jQuery plugins follow the following pattern:

```
$(function () {
    let settings;
    const methods = {};

    const init = function() {
        settings = {a:1};
        methods.b = function(){};
    };
});
```

Assuming I have a bunch of such plugins. Now I'm hoping to write a nodejs  program that will extract the `settings` and `methods` objects for each plugin for further doc generation. Now the things is the two objects are enclosed by `$(function(){});`. So I'm wondering whether there's any way for an external nodejs program to extract the two object from the plugins?

Update:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const fs = require('fs');

const header = `const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM("<!DOCTYPE html>");
var $ = require("jquery")(dom.window);`;

const pluginCode = fs.readFileSync('./dist/pager/pager.min.js', 'utf8');

const clientCode = `;$(function () { const $pager = $('<div/>').azPager(); console.log($pager) });`;

eval(header + pluginCode + clientCode);
```

I ended up writing some code like this, and it seems to work. It even outputs `jQuery { '0': HTMLDivElement {}, length: 1 }`. But I have some `import` statement in the plugin code which I have to comment them out.

Update:

Looks like problem solved by including not the source code of the plugin, but the compiled one.

Comment: Your node program reads the source, it does not run the jQuery code. There's nothing to do with introspection or reflection which happens at runtime. You just need a *documentation generator*, like jsdoc. There are many tools out there that do exactly this.

Comment: I don't need those fancy tools. I just want to extract these two objects and I can do my own.

Comment: You still cannot get that information at runtime though. It's static code analysis if anything.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen Well if you could do it yourself you wouldn't have to ask :-P But no, as the node.js program doesn't run the plugin and nothing gets loaded, there are no *objects*. It's just source code that you can extract from the file and analyse. You'll have a very hard time if those variables are populated dynamically.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen So yes, there is a way, but if you have trouble you will need to post the actual code of how the objects are populated (at least in this example plugin), and your attempt at writing the documentation program. Without those we cannot help you.

Comment: @Bergi I edited the question to the simplest form of my code. There's an `init` function need to be called. I cannot it do it this way, so that I asked, that does not mean I have to do it another way. It seems `jquery` together with `jsdom` can work together to enable jQuery to run in nodejs. Maybe I need to prepend some nodejs code to the plugin and require it. I will try and get back here to update.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen Yes, that could work - inject a callback code that makes the variables accessible from outside, then evaluate the plugin in a jsdom, then extract the object. But honestly that sounds much more complicated than the usual static documentation annotations :-)

Comment: static documentation annotations is not what I wanted because I don't want a doc site. I just want to extract these two little variables and I need to use them to generate some other little things. I updated the question. It seems `jsdom` + `jquery` works, but I have some `import` statement which i still a problem.